# How to judge enum value in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Here is example code:

```
enum DownloadItemStatus: Int {
    case Unstart, Prepare, Downloading, Paused, Finished, Failured
}

if status == .Unstart || status == .Paused || status == .Failured {
}
```

Is there a better method to judge the enum Value?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_enumerations.htm

Comment: Just read the chapter "Enumerations" in the Swift book ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `switch` statement :

```
switch (status) {
case .Unstart, .Paused, .Failured :
    // Do something
    break
case .Finished:
    // Do something else
    break 
default:
    // Handle all the others cases here
    break
}
```

Please note that in Swift, the break statement are not mandatory in order to avoid the fall through the next case block. I've only added them because you need at least one executable statement after each case test.

More infos about Switch statement available on the [Swift Programming  guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html).